# What is the pdf for a jointly uniform distribution inside a triangle?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have a triangle bounded by $0 \leq x, y \leq 1$ and $x + y \geq 1.5$. I'm told that points are uniformly distributed within this triangle.

I am wondering how I can find the pdf? Is it simply solving for the following?

$$
\int_{0.5}^1 \int_{0.5}^1 f(x,y) dx dy = 1 
$$

$f(x,y) = 4$ satisfies this equation, but is it unique?

Comment: The area is $8$, not $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition uniform density in  a region has a constant value equal to the reciprocal Of the  area of the region (and $0$ outside the region) . In this case the region is the triangle formed by the points $(1,1), (1,0.5)$ and $(0.5,1)$. So the density is $\frac  1 A$ for all points in this triangle where $A$ is the area. I will let you calculate the area.

Note that the limits for the integral are not the ones you have written. You should get  $\int_{0.5}^{1}\int_{1.5-y}^{1} f(x,y) dxdy$.

Comment: But the area is $\frac{1}{8}$. Are you saying the pdf is $8$? The pdf wouldn't integrate to 1 in this case.

Comment: Yes, you go the area right.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense if the pdf is $\frac{1}{A} = 8$ because $\int_{0.5}^1 \int_{0.5}^1 8 dxdy = 2$

Comment: @student010101 You have wrong limits for the integral. It should be $\int_{0.5}^{1}\int_{1.5-y}^{1} f(x,y) dxdy$.

Comment: Oh I see, how did you determine the limits of integration on over $x$?

Comment: You have to take into account the condition $x+y \geq 1.5$ or $x \geq 1.5-y$

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense. Is "By definition uniform density in a region has a constant value equal to the area of the region (and 0 outside the region)" a typo? Do you mean "...equal to the INVERSE of the area ..."?

Comment: Very true. I have corrected the answer.